# Mocking private fields with RhinoMocks

Tags: rhino-mocks, field, private

I have the following class definition whereby the `attribute` field is hydrated via reflection by NHibernate.  The field is not exposed as an object but instead I want to hide it's implementation and just provide properties that reference the properties of the `attribute` field.

```
    public class CustomerAttribute : ICustomerAttribute
{
    private IAttribute attribute;

    public string DisplayName 
    {
      get { return attribute.DisplayName;}

    }
```

}

I'm trying to mock this object with RhinoMocks but I'm not sure how to hydrate the `attribute` field for testing.  I've tried setting the `attribute` field manually via reflection but I get a proxy error from RhinoMocks (which makes sense).

So how do I hydrate the `attribute` field to I can test the properties of the CustomerAttribute object?

Here is my test right now...

```
        [Test]
    public void PropertiesTest()
    {
        MockRepository mock = new MockRepository();
        ICustomerAttribute attribute = mock.StrictMock<ICustomerAttribute>();

        //Set the attribute field
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(CustomerAttribute).GetField("attribute",
                                                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetField |
                                                      BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        fieldInfo.SetValue(attribute, new Domain.Attribute()); //This does not work

        Expect.Call(attribute.DisplayName).Return("Postal Code");
        mock.ReplayAll();

        Assert.AreEqual(true, attribute.DisplayName);
        mock.VerifyAll();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If CustomerAttribute is your subject under test (SUT) and IAttribute is a dependency that needs to be mocked for testing, IAttribute more than likely needs to be injectable into CustomerAttribute.  This should be done either via constructor (usually preferred) or property injection.  Look into "Inversion of Control" if you're not familiar with it already.

Also, ICustomerAttribute should NOT be created as a mock--the concrete type should be created explicitly (i.e. "new CustomerAttribute").  After all, CustomerAttribute (the implentation!) is the what you are trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to test here. If you want to test your CustomerAttribute class than you need to create an instance of it (instead of mocking ICustomerAttribute).

In order to set the attribute on your CustomerAttribute you could either

- Use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to inject the correct attribute and use it during testing
- Use reflection of the real CustomerAttribute instance you created for testing